# Add two text files to two columns in datagridview or listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview

I have been struggling with a problem for about a month now and felt it was time to come ask the pros.  I have a small program that scrapes data from a webpage.  Since it was the only way I could figure out, I scraped two different sets of data to two separate text files.  I have no trouble at all displaying one of the text files in the listview or datagridview components.  What I can't figure out for the life of me is how to display the second text file in the second column of either component (I am not using both components, I have merely tried using both).  Here is the code I use to display one file:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim col As New DataColumn("Title")
    Dim col2 As New DataColumn("Price")
    col.DataType = System.Type.[GetType]("System.String")
    dt.Columns.Add(col)
    dt.Columns.Add(col2)

    Dim aa As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\John\Documents\Title.txt")
    For Each item In aa
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        dr(0) = item.ToString()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs tidying but roughly

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    Dim col As New DataColumn("Title")
    Dim col2 As New DataColumn("Price")
    col.DataType = System.Type.[GetType]("System.String")
    dt.Columns.Add(col)
    dt.Columns.Add(col2)

    Dim aa As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\John\Documents\Title.txt")
    For Each item In aa
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr(0) = item.ToString()
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    Dim counter As Int32 = 0
    Dim RowCount As Int32 = dt.Rows.Count
    Dim bb As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\John\Documents\Title2.txt")
    For Each item2 In bb
        If (counter +1) > RowCount Then
            dr = dt.NewRow()
            dr(1) = item2.ToString()
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
         Else
            dr = dt.Rows(counter)
                dr(1) = item2.ToString()
                End If
    counter += 1
            Next

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Thank you! When I add this, however, nothing shows up in the datagridview.  Is this meant to be added to my existing code, or replace it?  Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Works perfectly...Now I can study the code to see why!  Thanks again!

Comment: Out of interest, how are you scraping data from webpages?